# Freetype 2, building visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, freetype, freetype2

Getting the following warning:

```
ttgload.c(1654): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'FT_UInt' to 'void *' of greater size
```

Which seems rather odd.

The line of code in question is this:

```
if ( FT_List_Find( &loader->composites,
                   (void*)(unsigned long)glyph_index ) )
```

and `glyph_index` is declared `FT_UInt`.

`FT_UInt` is `typedef unsigned int` so it is rather strange to convert an `int` to a `void*`.

Any ideas on how to deal with this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FT_UInt is typedef unsigned int so it is rather strange to convert an int to a void*.

Actually it's not. It's perfectly fine and allowed to convert between integers and pointers. A particular application of this is "user parameters" to a function where you register integer or a pointer together with a function callback.

However the two-fold typecast `(void*)(unsigned long)` is a recipe for getting problems. It's not guaranteed that `sizeof(unsigned ling) >= sizeof(void*)` which may cause all kinds of problems (i.e. undefined behaviour) of pointers get truncated.

The proper types to use when someone wants an integer that also can hold a pointer are `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`.

> Any ideas on how to deal with this warning?

In this particular case it's likely not a cause of problems, because that pointer is going to be cast back to an FT_UInt. In the long run it would make sense to file an issue and change the prototype of FT_List_Find to accept a `uintptr_t` instead of a pointer; unfortunately this would also break a lot of existing programs.

Comment: I agree that there is no problem for this particular case, but the warnings are still there anyway. One way to remove these few warnings are replace "unsigned long" by "size_t". So the conversion becomes (void*)(size_t), for which the compiler won't complain.